# Auto update import paths to alias in VS Code

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I've been working on a project and implemented aliases midway. Is there a way in VS Code to automatically update all the import paths to the new aliases so that I don't have to do it manually.

From this:

```
import button from '../../components/common/button'
```

To:

```
import button from '@components/common/button'
```

Automatically over all of the files.

Comment: I also was looking for a solution to this. Were you able to do this?

Comment: @bombillazo not natively unfortunately. Ended up doing it manually at the time, but in hindsight, a quick regex replacement can help. [Example](https://regex101.com/r/53MQEb/1)

Comment: @bombillazo I'd edit this regex a bit before using it, it's just a conceptual example and I can think of a couple of ways for it to fail